# APIGatewayRestResolver lambda function giving error "errorMessage": "'httpMethod'", "errorType": "KeyError" at app.resolve(event, context)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda-containers

I am using this [AWS LAMBDA POWERTOOLS](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/2.6.0/core/event_handler/api_gateway/#api-gateway-rest-api) to resolve lambda functions error to api gateway so that client receive correct error code instead of 200 always.

```
from aws_lambda_powertools import Logger, Tracer, Metrics
from aws_lambda_powertools.event_handler import APIGatewayRestResolver
from aws_lambda_powertools.logging import correlation_paths
from aws_lambda_powertools.utilities.typing import LambdaContext

tracer = Tracer()
logger = Logger()
metrics = Metrics()
app = APIGatewayRestResolver()


@app.post("/dept_predictor")
@tracer.capture_method
def dept_predictor():
    post_data: dict = app.current_event.json_body
    print(post_data)
    try:
        print("Received event: " + json.dumps( app.current_event, indent=2))
        print(type(event), '--> ', event)
        payload = event['data']
        print(payload)
    
        response  = runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME, 
                                                  ContentType='application/json', 
                                                  Body=json.dumps(payload),
                                                  Accept='Accept')
        print(response)
        print(response.keys())
      
        if "errorMessage" in response.keys() and "502 Bad Gateway" in str(response):
            return {"statusCode":"502",'body': response}
            
        elif "errorMessage" in response.keys() and "504 Gateway Time-out" in str(response):
            return {"statusCode":"504",'body': response}
        
            
        result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
        return {"statusCode":"200",'body': result}
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception----", traceback.print_exc())
        exception_handler(e)
```

Error message I am getting while testing the lambda function is below:

```
 {
  "errorMessage": "'httpMethod'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/opt/python/aws_lambda_powertools/logging/logger.py\", line 442, in decorate\n    return lambda_handler(event, context, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/aws_lambda_powertools/tracing/tracer.py\", line 305, in decorate\n    response = lambda_handler(event, context, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 85, in lambda_handler\n    return app.resolve(event, context)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/aws_lambda_powertools/event_handler/api_gateway.py\", line 540, in resolve\n    response = self._resolve().build(self.current_event, self._cors)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/aws_lambda_powertools/event_handler/api_gateway.py\", line 604, in _resolve\n    method = self.current_event.http_method.upper()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/aws_lambda_powertools/utilities/data_classes/common.py\", line 100, in http_method\n    return self[\"httpMethod\"]\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/aws_lambda_powertools/utilities/data_classes/common.py\", line 17, in __getitem__\n    return self._data[key]\n"
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue when I used

```
sam local invoke
```

I am now using this intead:

```
sam local start-api
```

Hope this helps?

Answer (score 1):

Powertools Python maintainer here. We don't actively monitor StackOverflow at the moment - only [GitHub](https://github.com/aws-powertools/powertools-lambda-python) and [Discord](https://discord.gg/B8zZKbbyET).

**As to your main question**. The reason you're getting this error is because the event payload is incorrect - this does not happen at runtime.

> At your convenience, [please open up an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aws-powertools/powertools-lambda-python/issues/new/choose) so we can improve the error messaging in the next release.

**Solution.**

- **Use AWS SAM CLI to emulate API Gateway**. Our [official tutorial](https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda-python/latest/tutorial/) covers that along with a project template with full instructions. Similar to what @user3246277 [suggested earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75731577/13700765)
- **Use a sample payload when invoking the handler**. If you are crafting an unit test, you can copy this [event sample](https://github.com/aws-powertools/powertools-lambda-python/blob/develop/tests/events/apiGatewayProxyEvent.json) and adjust the HTTP Method, Path, and Payload

That should help.